# Adding UIButton (follow button) in UITableView using swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, parse-platform, uibutton

So here is my Problem.. I've retrieved the user data from `_User` class in Parse and showing it in the app as follows:

```
var data:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()


func loadData() {

    data.removeAllObjects()

    var userQuery = PFUser.query()
        userQuery?.orderByAscending("createdAt")
        userQuery?.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, erroe) -> Void in

            if let objects = objects {

                for object in objects {

                    if let user = object as? PFUser {

                        if user.objectId != PFUser.currentUser()?.objectId {

                            self.data.addObject(object)



                        }

                        self.tableView.reloadData()


                    }

                }
            } 
        })
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    loadData()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return data.count

}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("users", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! userListTableViewCell

    let userData:PFObject = self.data.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! PFObject

    // Usernames and gender..

    myCell.fullName.text = userData.objectForKey("fullName") as! String!
    myCell.genderLabel.text = userData.objectForKey("gender") as! String!

    // Profile pictures..

    let profilePics = userData.objectForKey("profilePicture") as! PFFile
    profilePics.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (data, error) -> Void in

        if let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data!) {

            myCell.dp.image = downloadedImage
        }

    }
    return myCell
}
```

Now I want to add a follow button to follow a particular user and want to save that data in Parse. So my questions are:

1. How can I add the follow button effectively which would not mess up things if there are so many users.. I've tried giving them `tag` like `myCell.followButton.tag = indexPath.row` but it dint work well. so I want to know about some other way for achieving my goal.
2. What is the best possible way to save the follower list in Parse.. I'm thinking to make a class named `Followers` having the columns `user` : the user being followed and `follower` where we can add the `PFUser.currentUser().objectId` . Is there anything better than this or this is a nice method to do it?

here is the screen shot of my `userListTableViewController`..

[image]

Here you can see the followButton which i've already connected to `userListTableViewCell`.. Please help me out.. Thanks for your time..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets make that button you want a UILabel instead and add a UIGestureRecognizer to it, one like this

Create a swift file named `PFUserTapGestureRecognizer.swift`

```
import UIKit

class PFUserTapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer
{
    var tapper: PFUserTapper

    init(id: Int, onTap: (id: Int) -> Void)
    {
        self.tapper = PFUserTapper()
        self.tapper.id = id
        self.tapper.onTap = onTap
        super.init(target: self.tapper, action: Selector("userTapped"))
    }
}

class PFUserTapper : NSObject
{
    var id = 0
    var onTap: ((idUse: Int) -> Void)?

    func userTapped()
    {
        onTap?(idUser: id)
    }
}
```

Now, when you load your cell in your view controller where you are loading your UITableView, in the delegate `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, do this:

```
// Check if you are following that user already
// if im NOT following this user then
{
    let idUser = userData.objectForKey("id") as! Int
    myCell.labelFollow.tag = idUser
    myCell.labelFollow.text = "Follow"
    addFollowBehavior(follow: true, idUser: idUser, label: myCell.labelFollow)
}
// else if i'm following the user
{
    myCell.labelFollow.text = "Unfollow"
    addFollowBehavior(follow: false, idUser: idUser, label: myCell.labelFollow)
}
// else.. you should consider the case when you click Follow and it takes time to get an answer from your service
```

And create this function

```
func addFollowBehavior(follow follow: Bool, idUser: Int, label: UILabel) 
{
    if let recognizers = label.gestureRecognizers {
        for recognizer in recognizers {
            label.removeGestureRecognizer(recognizer as! UIGestureRecognizer)
        }
    }
    label.addGestureRecognizer(PFUserTapGestureRecognizer(idUser, 
        onTap: { (idUser) -> Void in
            // THIS IS WHERE YOU SAVE TO PARSE, WEB SERVICE OR WHATEVER
            // if follow then 
                // Do Follow 
            // else 
                // UnFollow... 

            // On the callback write this to protect from reused cells:
            if label.tag = idUser {
                myCell.labelFollow.text = follow ? "Unfollow" : "Follow" // NOW (UN)FOLLOWING!
                addFollowBehavior(follow: !follow, idUser: idUser, label: myCell.labelFollow)
            }
        }
    )
}
```

I didn't had the chance to test it but I have a very similar implementation on a requirement like that and it works perfectly

Note: this works if the follow item is an `UIImageView` or whatever inherits from `UIView` for a cooler look, instead of changing the text, you change the `UIImage`

Comment: how are you getting the information about already being followed users??  and can you please edit your answer to tell where exactly all the codes should i write(in which viewControllers) for more explanation ? Thanks

Comment: You should save somewhere the info of the users you are already following, and the code you add to the cell is very clear (I edited it anyway), use it in the viewcontroller where you are displaying the UITableView, and i'm not missunderstanding that you have a UIButton, I'm actually suggesting you to make it a UILabel or UIImageView, instead

Comment: i have `@IBOutlet var followButtton: UIButton!` in my `UITableViewCell`do i need to change something here??

Comment: Just the way you added that button to your interface, and then linked it to your class, do the same but with a UILabel

Comment: can you please update it with the followers data also?? because this code has many errors :/

Comment: there are missing code because you have to complete it, what you are asking is a different question and more detailed about your Business Logic

Comment: the missing code you need to added it were the comments appear like
   _// if im NOT following this user then_
Here you have to put code like:
    `if loggedUser.usersFollowed.contains(idUser) == false`

Comment: where is the data being saved here?? the followers and users?? want to save it in parse when that button is being pressed..

Comment: right bellow the comment of _// THIS IS WHERE YOU SAVE TO PARSE, WEB SERVICE OR WHATEVER_